# Can QGIS maptips handle iframes?

Tags: qgis, html, maptips

Is the QGIS maptip html code capable of handling iframes?

I have a point shapefile of river gauge station locations.  I would like to be able to embed the realtime gauge information from [Gauge Map](http://www.gaugemap.co.uk/) for each gauge into the map.  The gaugemap website allows you to embed the information into other websites through an iframe (see screengrab below).  However, copying the iframe text into the html section of the maptips for the layer in QGIS doesn't produce anything.

Am I doing it wrong?  Is it possible to pull this into QGIS through the maptips or might there be another way?

[image]

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using? I'm running 2.16.1 and copied the text straight from your screen shot and it worked fine for me.

Comment: Hi Knightshound - I'm running 2.14.3, the latest Kyngchaos build as I'm on mac.  I will switch over to windows, load the latest version and see what happens!

Comment: Map tips use a small web browser in 2.16 so that is why they work there, before 2.16 it wasn't.

Comment: Brilliant - thanks Nathan!  Enter that as an answer if you want and I'll mark it correct.  Fortunately I can work round it using the ID tool and setting it to display a web view of the widget source.